# Set shouldAutorotate to false with Photolibrary

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, shouldautorotate

If I add a popover with access to my photo gallery from the `iPad` the system always crash with the following message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

But I already set up in my Projekt Information just to support Landscape Mode.

So I added the following function

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {

    return false
}
```

But I don't know how to use it? If I enable `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` on my app too, it works fine. But I don't want to support `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`.

I'll call my popover like this:

```
var popover: UIPopoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: ImagePickerController)

popover.presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem(addImageButton, 
                                        permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, 
                                        animated: true)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have no choice. And in fact you have solved the problem already. As you have already said, the solution is to enable portrait orientation in your app. You don't have to use it in any of your other view controllers, but you must include it in the app's permissible orientations, because this one view controller that you are trying to show requires it. If the intersection between what the view controller requires and what the app permits is null, the app will crash (as you have seen).

Comment: So you mean that i just enable it, but how can i force Landscape Mode for my App?

Comment: Is this still up to date for iOS8/Swift? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6

Comment: "but how can i force Landscape Mode for my App" By having every single view controller that belongs to you permit only landscape, and by making sure that a landscape orientation is first in Info.plist listing. But _this_ view controller, the one you are having trouble with, will appear in portrait.

Comment: My book explains how the iOS app orientation mechanism works: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_rotation

Answer (score 2):

At a slightly higher level, the problem is that your app only supports landscape and yet the `UIImagePickerController` requires portrait to be supported in your app (but none of the view controllers, which makes no sense, but anyway...)

So another way to handle this problem is to look for an alternative to `UIImagePickerController` that does the same thing. Here's one that works well. While the code hasn't been updated in a few years, it is ARC compatible.

https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController

It's pretty fantastic, and helps you avoid lots of madness, especially if you don't want to (or cannot) support portrait modes in your app.