# ImagePickerController should open in landscape mode

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

`UIImagePickerController` should open in landscape? I tried using category but it is not working. how to fix orientation to a `UIImagePickerController` ?

Comment: See the Link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374237/using-uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape-orientation

Answer (score 0):

*You should use UIPopoverController to display ImagePickerController in Landscape mode*

```
-(void)showImagePicker:(id)sender
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; // button is on which user will tap to show image picker
        UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imgPicker.delegate = self;
        imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imgPicker];
        [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Try to create a custom class of UIImagePickerController. Override supportedInterfaceOrientations method in it:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
```