# How to open camera in landscape mode app in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an app in which I need to open the camera in a landscape mode app in iPhone. I Googled but couldn't find any healthy solution.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

picker.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController: picker animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using UIImagePickerController in landscape orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374237/using-uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape-orientation)

Comment: Only in iphone .......work propraly in ipad....

Comment: not a photoalbum but not open a camera.... app also landscape mode not used on Portrait mode.......... @pang