# iOS camera application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app that is a single view application,

I have embedded an Image View and a button in the first view of my app, 
On click of the button I call the UIImagePickerController,

Doing so opens up my phones camera and when I press the camera button, It gives me a view which is an image and has two buttons Use Photo and Retake,

I also want to add buttons to rotate the image and crop in this view,
But I am unable to understand how this view is generated, How can I modify it?

Comment: check this for landscape mode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374237/using-uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape-orientation

Comment: use this: https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController
When you get image from camera you can open this controller for extra menus for image editing.