# can i handle orientation of a viewcontroller using storyboard

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

i want to change the orientation of only one view controller. I found some answers where i have to set orientation in every view controller. Is there any easy way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466048/how-to-allow-only-single-uiviewcontroller-to-rotate-in-both-landscape-and-portra

Comment: Check out this answer (its swift) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42911102/cannot-get-landscape-with-portrait-mode-for-image-picker-to-work This will help you change a single VC to landscape/portrait whatever.

Comment: Duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/28938660/6044997  The best answer give a nice function so it's really easy to handle in your ocntrollers

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the orientation of only 1 view controller in your storyboard. But you can put your view in a xib file and add it in your storyboard.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34524583/2870477

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42911102/cannot-get-landscape-with-portrait-mode-for-image-picker-to-work

Comment: He said we want to change the orientation *using storyboard*, which is not possible. In the code, it's possible

Comment: Hmm, I misread it to quickly... If you edit your answer (just change 1 character) I can delete the downvote. Sorry.

Answer (score -2):

You can not change orientation for a single viewcontroller.
So you have to check mark for all device orientation in xcode for project and to stop orientation of all viewcontrollers except this one.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42911102/cannot-get-landscape-with-portrait-mode-for-image-picker-to-work