# can we use UIImagePickerController for Landscape iPad

Tags: ipad, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, landscape-portrait

problem state: I need to access photo library using

> UIImagePickerController

for Landscape iPad. This works fine in portrait mode but in Landscape app crashes.

how can use **UIImagePickerController**   to access photo library in Landscape mode. If not then any other alternative way to do this.

I tried these already

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool
{
    return false
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .all
}
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using UIImagePickerController in landscape orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374237/using-uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape-orientation)

Comment: I tried both of them

Answer (score 0):

This answer would help a lot. But it is written in Objective - C. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19630858/5807290. Happy Coding.

Comment: if you see in snippet ; portrait is checked too. so device goes to portrait mode while accessing photoLibrary